# Master.cs running after the page content codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, code-behind

I have an issue where I am setting session variables using the master page, then using those session variables to deal with content in my placeholder. However, the session variables are not showing as updated in the content. I've made a small example below.

I need the session variables to be updated in both the masterpage and the content. Right now, it's as if the content codebehind is running either before or simultaneous with the masterpage. I assumed that the masterpage codebehind would run first, thus setting the session variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (.NET 2.0 build using C#)

testmass.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" inherits="gpworklist.testmass"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html> 
    <head runat="server">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="testthisform">
    <select id="test1sel" name="test1" runat="server"></select>
    <select id="test2sel" name="test2" runat="server"></select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="testsess" runat="server"></div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cntnt_phldr" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </body>
</html>
```

testmass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace gpworklist
{
    public class testmass: MasterPage
    {
        public string defProv;

        public testmass()
        {
        }

        public void Page_Load()
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);

            HtmlSelect sel1 = (HtmlSelect)this.FindControl("ctl00$test1sel");
            HtmlSelect sel2 = (HtmlSelect)this.FindControl("ctl00$test2sel");
            HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)this.FindControl("ctl00$testsess");

            string def1;
            string def2;

            ListItem item;

            if (Request["ctl00$test1sel"] != null && Request["ctl00$test1sel"] != "")
            {
                Session["test1"] = Request["ctl00$test1sel"];
            }
            if (Request["ctl00$test2sel"] != null && Request["ctl00$test2sel"] != "")
            {
                Session["test2"] = Request["ctl00$test2sel"];
            }

            if (Session["test1"] != null)
            {
                def1 = Session["test1"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                def1 = "";
            }
            if (Session["test2"] != null)
            {
                def2 = Session["test2"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                def2 = "";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                item = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
                if (i.ToString() == def1)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
                sel1.Items.Add(item);
            }
            //Session["test1"] = sel1.Value;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                item = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
                if (i.ToString() == def2)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
                sel2.Items.Add(item);
            }
            Session["test2"] = sel2.Value;

            div.InnerHtml = Session["test1"] + " - " + Session["test2"];

        }
    }
}
```

testpage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="testmass.master" Inherits="gpworklist.testpage"%>
<asp:content ID="contentstuff" contentplaceholderid="cntnt_phldr" runat="server">
    <div id="testpagesess" runat="server"></div>
</asp:content>
```

testpage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace gpworklist
{
    public class testpage: Page
    {
        public testpage()
        {
        }

        public void Page_Load()
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);

            HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)this.FindControl("ctl00$cntnt_phldr$testpagesess");

            div.InnerHtml = Session["test1"] + " - " + Session["test2"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Init` event of the `MasterPage`, instead of the `Load` event. That will be called before the `Page.Load`.

Answer (score 2):

A content page's event does fire before the same master page's event.
see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dct97kc3(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dct97kc3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)